# java apache poi importing into netbeans 6.9

Tags: java

i downloaded apache.poi-src-3.7-20101029.zip and i want to use this package in my java application using netbeans 6.9 to get use of doc files.

How to configure that zip file into netbeans to get use of the package into java application

Answer (score 0):

Go to Projects...Select your Project...Right click on Properties->Libraries. Under Compile Tab Click Add. Browse to your zip and add it. Done! If your library is a Run time library [Which I think it isn't] you need to add it under the Run tab.

Comment: ....that library uses some of jdk packages like java.awt....i am getting still error

Comment: Can you specify what error you are getting? I imported the library into one of my project and there were no errors.

Comment: sir can i chat to u online in gtalk if u dont mine...i am unable to express the error....