# POI API APACHE importing to netbeans

Tags: java, apache, api, netbeans, apache-poi

I have read some tips in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989231/java-apache-poi-importing-into-netbeans-6-9) but i still cant do import like this:

```
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;
```

I have add the zip file (poi-src-3.8-20120326) that downloaded from [here](http://poi.apache.org/download.html) to library inmy neatbeans project.

Comment: What is the issue you are seeing? i.e. any error message?

Comment: Did you really mean to download the *source* release of POI (src = source), rather than the *binary* (bin) one?

Comment: i downloaded poi src and bin, which one i can use?

Comment: @munna i cannot import the library, it seem i've add the wrong library

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unzip the file you downloaded, find: `poi-3.8-20120326.jar`, open `NetBeans` project, find `Libraries`, right click on it and select `Add JAR/Folder`, select the `poi-3.8-20120326.jar` and thats it. When you do that you can use classes from `poi-3.8-20120326.jar`. This jar will be on your classpath.

Notice that in the unzipped directory there is also `lib` folder, these are the dependencies for `poi`, make sure you add them as well.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the compiled code on the class path. Rather than just the source code. Typically projects distribute these separately.

Take a look into using maven to automatically download dependencies and source for external projects such as poi.

Get the compile working outside of netbeans.
Only then open it in net beans.